# Measuring DOM content load time of pages that are rendered through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

For measuring the performance of website I use `window.performance.timing`. But it fails when I try to measure the performance of webpages that are rendered through ajax calls. For example, if the webpage is designed using frameworks like angularjs, then the pages can be rendered through ajax calls.

This is a screenshot of one such website that [loads pages by ajax calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbuoo.png)
. You can see (sorry for the poor quality) the `performance.timing` has given the same result in both pages.

To overcome this, I tried [PerformanceResourceTiming API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming). But this doesn't provide the DOM content load time.

How can I measure the DOM content load time of these pages using javascript?

Comment: If I were you, I would try to profile my app with the tools you can find in Chrome under the Performance tab. More info: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/

Comment: I am looking for a way to measure the performance of all websites and not just my website.

Comment: It works for other websites too.

Answer (score 0):

Call `console.time('yourVarNameHere')` when just before initiating an ajax request and `console.timeEnd('yourVarNameHere')` after it's complete and the DOM has been updated as necessary based on what came back.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time

Comment: This gives the elapsed between making an ajax request and receiving the response, which is the **response time** of the website. (Correct me if I am wrong). I need the DOM load time.

Comment: Okay @amedina. I was about to try that later. I'll check it right now.

Comment: @amedina the profiler displays graphs only when I explicitly refresh the page. I need to capture it programmatically. What should I do for this?

Comment: @PrasanthG In that case and taking into account that you want to profile the DOM load time... I don't know. Well, there are methods that may help you: `console.profile()` and `console.profileEnd()`. Check them out: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/api

Comment: @PrasanthG I would say it sort of depends on where you put the `time` and `timeEnd` statements. You could start timing after the request is complete but before you start manipulating the DOM. But my suggested approach is definitely a simplistic one, and may not necessarily be easy to integrate with frameworks.